# Java Tibco EMS get queue list without using TibjmsAdmin

Tags: java, tibco-ems

I am using the following code to establish a connection to tibco ems.

```
TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory(server.url, null, environment);

QueueConnection connection = factory.createQueueConnection(server.user, server.password);       
QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

TibjmsAdmin = new TibjmsAdmin(server.url, server.user, server.password, environment);

QueueInfo[] queueInfo = admin.getQueues();
```

The `getQueues` request throws exception that the user is not authorized to execute the command. Before going ahead with a request to their admin (this ems belongs to another company), I would like to clarify few things so that I can avoid an outright denial of permission.

1) By any chance a user who is able to connect to the server can list the queues without using the TibjmsAdmin interface? I read about JNDI lookups, but could not find any complete example for EMS. Can this JNDI achieve this, using only the connection permission?

2) Can the EMS administrator permit listing of only a subset of queues to a user, which the `admin.getQueues()` can retrieve? I read about pattern based permission. Could someone give an example of the `grant` command the EMS admin would use to do that?

3) What command does the ems admin use to grant `show queues` permission to a user. I have installed a trial version of ems server. I could give `all` admin privileges to another user, but not the minimum required permission to do a `show queues`. I have tried almost all possible combinations I could think of, but to no avail.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Login using an admin account and grant view permission to your user using below command (Don't forget to specify the correct 'userName').

```
grant admin user=userName view-all
```